# Django - Use getattr() to retrieve Model Method (@property)

Tags: python, django, django-models, getattr

I would like to do this:

```
def retrieve_data(self, variable):
    start_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(int(self.kwargs['days']))
    invoice_set = InvoiceRecord.objects.filter(sale_date__gte=start_date)
    total = 0
    for invoice in invoice_set:
        for sale in invoice.salesrecord_set.all():
            total += getattr(self, variable)
    return round(total)
```

Where variable is submitted as a string that represents one of my model methods:

```
@property
def total_sale(self):
    return self.sales_price * self.sales_qty
```

But my effort doesn't work:

```
def total_sales(self):
    return self.retrieve_data(variable="total_sale")
```

It simply says:

> 'SalesSummaryView' object has no attribute 'total_sale'

Evidently, I am misunderstanding the usage. Can someone help me figure out a way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: You should be able to get a property via `getattr` just fine.  Is `total_sales` defined on the `SalesSummaryView` class or something else?

Comment: It's defined on my model, which is why this wasn't working. I had gotten confused. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I was calling getattr() on the view, rather than the model. Instead of using self, I needed to submit the `sale` object.

```
for invoice in invoice_set:
    for sale in invoice.salesrecord_set.all():
        total += getattr(sale, variable)
```